# Flask custom error handler not correctly handling registered error type

Tags: python, exception, flask

I've created a basic Flask app and registered a custom error handler for a particular custom exception type. When this exception type is thrown and passed up the stack, however, Flask does not use the specified custom error handler.

I've created a second error handler with the base Exception type, which successfully catches the error. The base exception handler's presence does not affect the custom error handler's ability to catch errors, if the base handler isn't present, the error bubbles all the way up to the default Flask 500 page.

I've also done `print(srv.error_handler_spec)`, and it seems that the error handler is successfully being registered.

Here is the main portion of `srv.py`, the entry point for my Flask app

```py
from flask import Flask, request
from flask import jsonify

srv = Flask(__name__)

class APIError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, message, status_code=500):
        Exception.__init__(self)
        self.message = message
        self.status_code = status_code

    def log_error(self):
        logging.error(f"API error: {self.to_json()}")

    def to_dict(self):
        return {"message": self.message, "status_code": self.status_code}


@srv.errorhandler(Exception)
def exception_handler(e: Exception):
    response = jsonify(
        {"message": f"unhandled exception encountered", "status_code": 500}
    )
    logging.error(f"unhandled exception encountered. type: {e.__class__}")
    response.status_code = 500
    return response


@srv.errorhandler(APIError)
def api_error_handler(e: APIError):
    response = jsonify(e.to_dict())
    response.status_code = e.status_code
    return response


print(srv.error_handler_spec)


@srv.route("/", methods=["GET"])
def hello_world():
    return "hello world"


@srv.route("/error", methods=["GET"])
def error():
    raise APIError("generic error", status_code=400)
```

This is the log output from Flask when curling `/error`

```
[32mapp_1      |[0m {None: {None: {<class 'Exception'>: <function exception_handler at 0x7f211b8a5598>, <class 'srv.APIError'>: <function api_error_handler at 0x7f211b8a5620>}}}
[32mapp_1      |[0m {None: {None: {<class 'Exception'>: <function exception_handler at 0x7f211b8a5e18>, <class '__main__.APIError'>: <function api_error_handler at 0x7f211b8a5ea0>}}}
[32mapp_1      |[0m  * Serving Flask app "srv" (lazy loading)
[32mapp_1      |[0m  * Environment: production
[32mapp_1      |[0m    WARNING: Do not use the development server in a production environment.
[32mapp_1      |[0m    Use a production WSGI server instead.
[32mapp_1      |[0m  * Debug mode: off
[32mapp_1      |[0m  * Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
[32mapp_1      |[0m ERROR:root:unhandled exception encountered. type: <class 'srv.APIError'>
[32mapp_1      |[0m 172.27.0.5 - - [04/May/2019 06:52:47] "POST /api/user/create HTTP/1.1" 500 -
[32mapp_1      |[0m INFO:werkzeug:172.27.0.5 - - [04/May/2019 06:52:47] "POST /api/user/create HTTP/1.1" 500 -
[32mapp_1      |[0m 172.27.0.5 - - [04/May/2019 06:52:47] "GET /error HTTP/1.1" 400 -
[32mapp_1      |[0m INFO:werkzeug:172.27.0.5 - - [04/May/2019 06:52:47] "GET /error HTTP/1.1" 400 -
```

As you can see from the log line `ERROR:root:unhandled exception encountered. type: <class 'srv.APIError'>` it's using the generic `Exception` handler and not the custom one for `APIError`.

The expected behavior is that instead that Flask would instead use the custom error handler and print no log line at all.

For the record, the results from `curl` are consistent with the generic error handler returning the response. This is definitely not an issue with the generic handler clobbering the more specific handler. (Although that would also be erroneous according to Flask's documentation).

What gives?

Comment: APIError inherit from Exception, so basically, it's also an Exception. In your code, you register handler for Exception before APIError, it may be the case. Could you try moving the registration for APIError up and see if it works? In other words, try to put the Exception handler at last.

Comment: I tried that, it doesn't affect the outcome. Additionally, I indicated before that removing the Exception error handler just causes the APIError to bubble to the top, it still doesn't get caught by the remaining error handler.

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround, which is to place the `APIError` definition into a separate Python file and import it into `srv.py`.

The reason it's failing is because `isinstance()` doesn't work correctly. The exception that gets raised has type `srv.APIError`, but the type it's checked against is `__main__.APIError`, which are not the same type.

This is not due to type shadowing from another module, because changing the error type name to `StupidError` gives the same results.

I still don't know why this happens in the first place, however. :/